# Google search box not working, no console errors

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I'm practicing coding jQuery and Ajax and making a plain Google search box, but it won't work. There's no console errors and debugging in Chrome doesn't help much. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "http://www.google.com/search",
                dataType : "html",
                success : function(data) {
                    $("#show").html(data)
                },
                fail : function() {
                    alert("failed lol")
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search">
        <form name="input" method="get">
            Google it: <input type="text" name="googleit" /> <br /> <br /> <input
                id="button" type="button" value="let me google that for you" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="show"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a cross-domain call that easily, it's restricted by [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Check your network tab, it should state that the Request failed.

Also you didn't even hand over the value of your input-field. You should append it to the url like this `?q=hello`.

```
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + $("input").val(),
            dataType : "html",
```

You need a so called [JSONP-call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to access other domains.

Take a look at the [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

Comment: If you actually request a more specific page, with actual data instead of a redirect, such as `http://www.google.com/search?q=hello` then you'll see the Cross-Origin error.